# Solving race conditions in OAuth token refresh

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, mutex

I have a Web App that calls another API to get OAuth Token.

The WebApp can fire multiple calls at once.
The logic goes, if a token has expired, go get a new one using the refresh token.
I am now facing a Race Condition problem, as the new token returned, after its being refreshed is invalidated by subsequent calls to the Refresh endpoint.

I had an attempt to use Mutex to limit one call a time. My understanding is, Mutex is used to block threads on the entire assembly, whereas I would need it to be User-Based.

Any suggestions how this can be tackled? Appreciate any advice.

Comment: You haven't tagged a language, but your previous questions seem to be about ASP.NET Core, so I'm guessing that's maybe what your web app is written in. If that's the case, I suggest using a `SemaphoreSlim`- one per user.

Comment: If this is a Javascript app just store the promise of the currently-in-flight refresh.

Comment: it is c# asp.net

Comment: I just discovered another technique, called Locks? Would that solve the issue?

Comment: Do you expect your solution to scale to more than one web server?

Comment: No, I wouldn't be scaling.